# My Scooter is not starting

Tags: starting, battery-drain

My Scooter,Activa is not starting.
Accidentally I kept my ignition on for 2 days
What to do?
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How many kms it has clocked?Were you facing starting issue before also?

Comment: Have you tested, recharged the battery? Seems the obvious steps to take.

Comment: Battery is my money- do the lights work?